# 403 Forbidden POST - Flask WTForms

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask Application running on Google App Engine. I am trying to submit a form built using WTForm and I keep getting the following error.

403 Forbidden: You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Location.html (Part of the code)

```
    <form method=post action="/home/location">
    ....
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        Directions
                    </button>
    </form>
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/home/location', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def location():
    form = cfcdirections.Direction(request.form)
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print("After if")
        directions = cfcdirections()
        street_no = directions.No
        street = directions.Street
        suburb = directions.Suburb
        postcode = directions.Postcode
        state = directions.State
    return render_template('Location.html',form=form)
```

Comment: Are you including the [CSRF token](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) in your form?

Comment: I am using a Flask Extension @app.before_request
def csrf_protect():
    if request.method == "POST":
        token = session.pop('_csrf_token',None)
        if not token or token != request.form.get('_csrf_token'):
            abort(403)

Comment: Yes, and in your template, are you including the token?

Comment: AH ... yes I see. I did not include it in this form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you just have to post this in the answer: `{{form.csrf_token}}` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to include the [CSRF token](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) in your form:

```
<form method=post action="/home/location">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    ....
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    Directions
                </button>
</form>
```